# O(n log n) Time Complexity Algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, time, big-o

I created this algorithm to find the best trade between 3 numbers. It goes through the program and finds the best day to sell, buy, and profit from stock. I need to explain the algorithm used and how the time complexity is O(n log n) but I have a lot of trouble determining that. I was hoping someone could explain O(n log n) and relate it to the method I have.

Here's my method:

```
public static Trade bestTrade(int[] a) 
   {
      int lowest = a[0];
      int lowestIndex = 0;
      int highest = a[a.length - 1];
      int highestIndex = a.length - 1;
      int profit = 0;

      for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) 
      {
         if (a[i] < lowest && i < highestIndex) 
         {
            lowest = a[i];
            lowestIndex = i;
         }  
      }

      for(int i = a.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) 
      {
         if (a[i] > highest && i > lowestIndex) 
         {  
            highest = a[i];   
            highestIndex = i;
         }  
      }

      for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) 
      {
         if (a[i] < lowest && i < highestIndex) 
         {   
            lowest = a[i];   
            lowestIndex = i;
         }  
      }

      if (highestIndex > lowestIndex) 
      {
         profit = highest - lowest;
         return new Trade(lowestIndex, highestIndex, profit);
      }

      return new Trade(lowestIndex, highestIndex, profit);
   }

}
```

Comment: On first glance it looks like it's actually O(3n) which equates to O(n).

Comment: Looks O(n) to me. All loops are linear. No recursion.

Comment: So to make it the time complexity O(n log n) I would need to combine my for loops? sorry, kind of new to this.

Comment: @kids O(n log n) algorithms are usually divide and conquer sorting algorithms that involve recursion.  Nested loops usually result in n squared runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This function is of O(n) which is superior to O(n log n) .
In general you just look at the loops, since there is no nested loops and you only have loops which go through all elements of a The function is considered n.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is O(n), where n the length of array a.

You loop 3 times over a, so the running time is roughly 3n, so it is of the order n: O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the answer to this by yourself. It will help a lot in the future. Also this looks like a O(N) , I am not sure why you are convinced that it is O(NlogN).

This link might be useful,
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html

Answer (score 1):

O(n)

It is directly proportional to the number of a.length. Each time the for function is run, it runs through every day of data. If there were a method where the number of processes went up by more than the pure number (nested fors) then it could be O(n log n) or O(n^2). But in this case, it's pretty clearly just big O of n.

Comment: So I need a group of nested fors to create O(n log n) complexity? @AlexG

Comment: O(n log n) would look like this:
for(int i =1; i < a.length; i++){
     for(int j = i; i < a.length; j++){
          code_here;
     }
}
Because as a.length goes up, the number of calculations will go up more than a result of a multiple of a.length, but less than that of squaring a.length.